# After creating cloudformer template and stack, what to do?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

i have created a cloudformer template, such as below

"template_test, 2018-03-08 07:19:05, CREATE_COMPLETE, AWS CloudFormer Beta - template creation prototype application"

then i created a stack from it, such as below

"CloudFormerLaunchedStack, 2018-03-08 07:45:46, ROLLBACK_COMPLETE, stack_test"

What can i do with the stack ? Can i create instance or anything from the stack?

Answer (score 1):

You know that [CloudFormer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html) is a tool that you use to create CloudFormation templates *from* your existing AWS resources, yes?

It looks like your stack creation failed and was rolled back. You'll need to [troubleshoot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/troubleshooting.html) that first.

Once you've created your CloudFormer stack successfully, follow the [instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html). Specifically, you need to launch CloudFormer by browsing to its web URL and then follow the guidance there.

Comment: Yes, i use the cloudformer tool only after i have read the document at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html

Comment: How to debug the failure of stack creation? Ok, found it. go to Events.]

Comment: "CloudFormerLaunchedStack, 2018-03-08 09:28:44 UTC+0800, CREATE_COMPLETE, description" , i have created a stack from the cloudformer template

Comment: After creating the stack, what to do with it ?

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you explain why you are using CloudFormer. What is it that you hope to do with CloudFormer?

Comment: It automatically starts the EC2 instance after creating the stack ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have 2 EC2 instance and a VPC. I would like to start the same two instances with the same settings.

Comment: The CloudFormer instructions previously provided show you how to browse to the CloudFormer EC2 instance, how to log in, and how to select the AWS resources that you want to be included in the CoudFormation template that CloudFormer will create for you.

Comment: I notice the cloud former tool can create instances with same memory size, with same volume size, and auto start the instances, but it is without the files in the volume (empty volume). So cloud former tools is not able to create volume (EBS) with the same files as in existing instance?

Comment: You can read about EBS and snapshots at https://blog.skeddly.com/2017/03/ebs-snapshots-explained.html. There's a certain level of knowledge that needs to be learned about AWS before you can successfully do what you're trying to do here. I know it sounds trivial but it's not.

Comment: Thank you. We need to create snapshot of existing volume, create a volume, and attach it to the new instance, then we can copy the files over to the new instance.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html):

> CloudFormer is a template creation beta tool that creates an AWS
>   CloudFormation template from existing AWS resources in your account.
>   You select any supported AWS resources that are running in your
>   account, and CloudFormer creates a template in an Amazon S3 bucket.

When you run the CloudFormer stack, it creates a CloudFormation template of the existing AWS resources in your account. If the CloudFormation stack that you are trying to spin up is failing, you need to troubleshoot that in the the CloudFormation dashboard / console. It gives a error message that will point you to the failed resource which you can troubleshoot and rectify.